# How to Replace a CCString?

Tags: cocos2d-x

Is there anything similar to a string Replace method for CCString? something like that takes another 2 CCString parameters, switching the first with the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to implement it yourself like the following.

```
#include <string>

using std::string;

CCString* replaceCCString(CCString* cs, const CCString* csearch, const CCString* creplace)
{
    string s = cs->getCString();
    string search = csearch->getCString();
    string replace = creplace->getCString();

    for (size_t pos = 0; ; pos += replace.length()) {
        pos = s.find(search, pos);
        if (pos == string::npos)
            break;

        s.erase(pos, search.length());
        s.insert(pos, replace);
    }

    return CCString::create(s);
}
```